# Can a theory contain postulates of other theories?

Tags: models, foundations

I was reading about kinetic theory of gases and its postulates (assumptions). What I can't understand is for example in the derivation of:

$$PV=\frac{2}{3}K$$

It uses the fact that:

$$F =\frac{ΔP}{Δt}$$

Isn't that fact based on Newtonian Mechanics?

Another theory that is based on three postulates (according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_state_theory)) is transition state theory. But it also uses theorems or quantities from thermodynamics (e.g. enthalpy, Gibbs free energy etc).

Isn't a physical theory considered as a specific set of hypothesis/assumptions (postulates)? Why it can be considered a "theory" if it uses postulates from another theory? In general in an aixomatic system there are the primitive terms and the axioms. These are the only elements that are needed to derive theorems etc. So in the above example there is no reason why the force should equal the rate of change of momentum.

What I am thinking is that when a new theory "pops up" its postulates can be regarded as extension of one more general physical theory. Is that how it works?

Comment: Would you ban me from using induction in calculus?

Comment: The word "theory", like every other word in the English language, is sometimes used loosely.

Answer (score 3):

> What I am thinking is that when a new theory "pops up" its postulates can be regarded as extension of one more general physical theory. Is that how it works?

Yes.  I'm not sure how one might expect otherwise - imagine wanting to understand the properties of a gas in terms of the average behavior of its constituent atoms, but then saying "well, this is a new theory, so I must forget everything I know about physics."  Where would you *start* from?

Physics is an empirical science, the goal of which is to understand the way the universe operates. It can be a useful exercise to organize various subfields of physics into a coherent logical structure, and if you do this, classical kinetic theory comes somewhere downstream of Newtonian point mechanics.

However, physics is not a lifeless, sterilized series of boxes into which every concept fits neatly and separated from every other. Most theories and models and frameworks are informed by many others, and there are no clean lines which separate one subject from another.  There are broad conceptual relationships which are important to understand, but trying to be excessively clinical about what constitutes a theory is, in my opinion, a truly pointless exercise for a physicist (though a philosopher of physics may find the prospect more appealing).

Comment: Most theories are rigorously mathematical, which makes categorizing them rather trivial. For example, theories that demand Lorentz invariance, and theories that don't.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is that the term "Theory" is not well defined.

Kinetic Gas Theory is a subset of Newtonian Mechanics, meaning it automatically assumes all of its postulates (You could also replace Newtonian with Relativity and get Relativistic Kinetic Gas Theory).

Some people might say that this is obvious, but it's not: sometimes, we have new breakthrough theories that completely reject older fundamental postulates. For example, Special Relativity rejects Galilean Relativity.

Because of that, personally, I agree with you that it would be good if it's definition was "A model that doesn't require any other assumptions". It would stop a lot of confusion and make science easier to learn.

Comment: I'm not as convinced it is quite so simple to categorize all different physical theories. Thermodynamics and statistical mechanics can be applied to classical, non-relativistic physics. But, it does not assume classical, non-relativistic physics, and can also be applied to situations where one or both of relativity and quantum mechanics is important.

Comment: @Andrew "Applying" statistical mechanics to classical physics is another way of saying "assume the postulates of both", so in that case classical statistical mechanics is a subset of both theories. Though maybe "subset" is not the best term. Maybe something more like a tag system, "Assumes X", "Assumes Y", etc. If you're not clear others might not know if you're talking about quantum s.m. or classical s.m. or just s.m.

Comment: Maybe. But given that the core ideas of statistical mechanics do not depend on whether the system is classical, quantum, and/or relativistic, it seems that adding "tags" to statistical mechanics is forcing the terminology to fit a particular idea of how theories should be categorized, rather than accurately describing what statistical mechanics says.

Comment: @Andrew "empty" s.m. would only have its own tag, solely so that it's clear it's "empty". I'm any case, i hardly consider it physics, more like math. You need to include either newton or quantum in it to get any actual physical predictions. But ultimately all of this is just my subjective suggestion...